Conditioning the BlurView on Android devices - React Native
I just wan't to get some feedbacks about rendering BlurView on low level devices.
I like to use Blur effect in some components. They works pretty well on IOS devices since IOS handles the drawing such effect differently than Android.
However on the Android side, Blur effects on the low end devices, has a expensive performance cost, which is affecting the UX.
When this is the case, i decided to make a condition to prevent rendering the BlurView on some devices. But i cannot decide what should be the exact case for such thing. Maybe i should split by Android version, but in this case there are people who can install higher versions of Android even their devices won't support it.
Maybe i need to check memory size of a devices and put condition there. Like if the total memory is lower than 4096 do not render blur but may be linear-gradient instead.
I'm so open for every single feedback.
If there are android developers who has more information about this stuff, please welcome :)
